# Can we compare the NSString with NSMutableString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, equals, nsmutablestring

for example...

```
NSString string1 = @"Hello world";
NSMutableString string2 = [NSMutableString stringWithString: string1];
```

then... then can we compare these using following statement..? or there is any other way?

```
if(string1 isEqualToString:string2)
```

help me out please...

Comment: So long as you correct your if statement to read: `if([string1 isEqualToString:string2])` then yes, your code is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes of course. an NSMutableString is an NSString, so your code is perfectly correct, except for some syntax errors (you missed the `*` on each `NSString` and the `[` `]` on the `if` statement. You should write :

```
NSString *string1 = @"Hello world";
NSMutableString *string2 = [NSMutableString stringWithString:string1];

if ([string1 isEqualToString:string2])
{
    // string are equal
}
```